# Are "big sisters" and "big daddies" actually girls and men, or are they nicknames for them?

Tags: bioshock, bioshock-2

I'm wondering if they are just nicknames given to the type of enemy, or if they are really "big sisters" (in oppose to "little sister") and men inside the "big daddy" suit. I know it really doesn't matter, but I'm very curious about who these enemies are.

Answer (score 8):

*Sisters* and *daddies* are indeed people, despite their monstrous appearance. However, they aren't necessarily related by blood or otherwise.

*Little sisters* are little girls who have been implanted with a parasite that uses blood to produce Adam. *Little sisters* collect and drink the blood of corpses to feed those parasites.

*Big daddies* are men, who have been physically and mentally altered. They were created as a countermeasure to people hunting *little sisters* for the Adam they produce. *Delta*, the protagonist of Bioshock 2, is one of the first *big daddies* in existence (possibly the fourth, as "delta" is the fourth letter of the greek alphabet).

The *Big sisters* are merely *little sisters* after they've grown up.

Comment: There is actually more than one Big Sister. They are simply post-pubescent Little Sisters.

Comment: @Yuki Thanks for the heads-up. I haven't played Bioshock 2 in years and my memory was kinda fuzzy. I only remember ever fighting *Delta*'s *sister* though.